# jquery dialog did not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-dialog

in my code i have a problem when i add jquery dialog it is not working ,  i have a jquery auto-complete js also added and it working fine. 
i tried but it didn't

when the button (btn_view_p) click i want to open the div id="dialog" in a dialog box

any ideas

here is the code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //-----------------------------------------------
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        $("#p_s_name").autocomplete("get_reg_num.php", {
            width: 260,
            matchContains: true,        
            selectFirst: false
        });
        $("#p_r_no").autocomplete("get_prisoners.php", {
            width: 260,
            matchContains: true,        
            selectFirst: false
        });
        //---------------------------------------

      $("#dialog").dialog({
              autoOpen:false,
              width:600,
              height:300,
              show:{
                  effect:"blind",
                  duration:1000
                  },
               hide:{
                   effect:"blind",
                   duration:1000
                   }      

          });
           $("#btn_view_p").click(function() {
          $("#dialog").dialog( "open" );
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
```

here is the html code

```
    <div id="content">
<table width="874" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tb1">
  <tr>
    <td width="121">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center"><h1>Find Prisoner</h1></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Register Number</p></td>
    <td width="349"><label>
      <input type="text" name="p_s_name" id="p_s_name" class="backG">
    </label></td>
    <td width="162"><p>Enter The Name</p></td>
    <td width="242"><label>
      <input type="text" name="p_r_no" id="p_r_no" class="backG">
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="button" name="btn_view_p" id="btn_view_p" value="Find"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>



    <div id="dialog">

    <table width="830" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">Details Of The Prisoner</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>




    </div>
```

Comment: Define "dialog it is not working".

Answer (score 0):

I don't see jqueryui css file.
Check the console for errors.

Comment: I've tested your code and is working. Did you check for errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some of the things in your code.First of it is jquery-ui.css.
secon thing is that you need to hide your dialog box detail up-front.
here is link of Pen in which i have modified your code so that it work.

[Link](http://codepen.io/techhysahil/pen/LEYeWB) `for Codepen`  **//Sorry for the wrong Link earlier**

Suggestion : i don't know why are you using table structure. Try to work with Div.